# WooCommerce export product XML to array

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, woocommerce

I have exported data from a WP WooCommerce (bookstore) and I want to import these data into a new project e-shop. I have written a function to read the XLM file and I'm pretty close to recovering all data needed like ID, ISBN, Title, and description but I need other information in `"<wp:postmeta>"` like the weight, regular and current price but I don't know how to process?

I have tested `str_replace()` for the `<wp:postmeta>` and it works but not for the `<wp:meta_key><wp:meta_value>`

The cleanest method is possible?

text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:excerpt="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/excerpt/"
  xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
  xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  xmlns:wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/"
>

<channel>
    <title>Librairy</title>
    <link>http://projet.fr</link>
    <description>Promesse</description>
    <pubDate>Thu, 22 Sep 2022 15:59:59 +0000</pubDate>
    <language>fr-FR</language>
    <wp:wxr_version>1.2</wp:wxr_version>
    <wp:base_site_url>http://projet.fr</wp:base_site_url>
    <wp:base_blog_url>http://projet.fr</wp:base_blog_url>

        <wp:author><wp:author_id>1</wp:author_id><wp:author_login
      ><![CDATA[author-admin]]></wp:author_login><wp:author_email
      ><![CDATA[an-email]]></wp:author_email><wp:author_display_name
      ><![CDATA[author-admin]]></wp:author_display_name><wp:author_first_name
      ><![CDATA[Admin]]></wp:author_first_name><wp:author_last_name
      ><![CDATA[AdminRoot]]></wp:author_last_name></wp:author>
    <generator>https://wordpress.org/?v=6.0.2</generator>
<image>
    <url>url of the product</url>
    <title>Librairy</title>
    <link>http://projet.fr</link>
    <width>32</width>
    <height>32</height>
</image> 
        <wp_options>                 <wp_option>
                    <name>shopengine_template__post_meta__shop</name>
                    <val>0</val>
                </wp_option>
                                <wp_option>
                    <name>shopengine_template__post_meta__archive</name>
                    <val>0</val>
                </wp_option>
                                <wp_option>
                    <name>shopengine_template__post_meta__single</name>
                    <val>0</val>
                </wp_option>
                                <wp_option>
                    <name>shopengine_template__post_meta__cart</name>
                    <val>2886</val>
                </wp_option>
                                <wp_option>
                    <name>shopengine_template__post_meta__checkout</name>
                    <val>0</val>
                </wp_option>
                                <wp_option>
                    <name>shopengine_template__post_meta__quick_view</name>
                    <val>0</val>
                </wp_option>
                
        </wp_options> 
    
    <item>
        <title><![CDATA[Routes Maritimes]]></title>
        <link>Link to the product</link>
        <pubDate>Thu, 28 Apr 2022 16:05:27 +0000</pubDate>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[admin]]></dc:creator>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">perma link a the product</guid>
        <description />
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p style="text-align: center;"><em>Description Test</em></p>]]></content:encoded>
        <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[de Alain Dayan]]></excerpt:encoded>
        <wp:post_id>114</wp:post_id>
        <wp:post_date><![CDATA[2022-04-28 16:05:27]]></wp:post_date>
        <wp:post_date_gmt><![CDATA[2022-04-28 16:05:27]]></wp:post_date_gmt>
        <wp:post_modified><![CDATA[2022-09-28 09:02:54]]></wp:post_modified>
        <wp:post_modified_gmt><![CDATA[2022-09-28 09:02:54]]></wp:post_modified_gmt>
        <wp:comment_status><![CDATA[open]]></wp:comment_status>
        <wp:ping_status><![CDATA[closed]]></wp:ping_status>
        <wp:post_name><![CDATA[routes-maritimes]]></wp:post_name>
        <wp:status><![CDATA[publish]]></wp:status>
        <wp:post_parent>0</wp:post_parent>
        <wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>
        <wp:post_type><![CDATA[product]]></wp:post_type>
        <wp:post_password><![CDATA[]]></wp:post_password>
        <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>
                                        <category domain="pa_pages" nicename="254"><![CDATA[254]]></category>
        <category domain="pa_isbn" nicename="9782324018121"><![CDATA[9782324018121]]></category>
        <category domain="product_tag" nicename="bateau"><![CDATA[bateau]]></category>
        <category domain="pa_edition" nicename="grund"><![CDATA[Gründ]]></category>
        <category domain="product_cat" nicename="histoire"><![CDATA[Histoire]]></category>
        <category
        domain="product_tag" nicename="histoire"><![CDATA[histoire]]></category>
        <category domain="product_tag" nicename="mer"><![CDATA[mer]]></category>
        <category domain="product_cat" nicename="nouveautes"><![CDATA[Nouveautés]]></category>
        <category domain="product_tag" nicename="paquebot"><![CDATA[paquebot]]></category>
        <category domain="product_tag" nicename="route"><![CDATA[route]]></category>
        <category domain="product_type" nicename="simple"><![CDATA[simple]]></category>
        <category domain="product_tag" nicename="titanic"><![CDATA[titanic]]></category>
        <category domain="product_cat" nicename="univers-adulte"><![CDATA[Univers adulte]]></category>
        <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_edit_last]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[total_sales]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[0]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_tax_status]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[taxable]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_tax_class]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[livres]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_manage_stock]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[yes]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_backorders]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[no]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_sold_individually]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[no]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_virtual]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[no]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_downloadable]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[no]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_download_limit]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[-1]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_download_expiry]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[-1]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_stock]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[4]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_stock_status]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[instock]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_wc_average_rating]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[0]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_wc_review_count]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[0]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_product_attributes]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value
        ><![CDATA[a:3:{s:10:"pa_edition";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:10:"pa_edition";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";i:0;s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:7:"pa_isbn";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:7:"pa_isbn";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";i:1;s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:8:"pa_pages";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:8:"pa_pages";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";i:2;s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}}]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_product_version]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[6.9.4]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_thumbnail_id]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[115]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_sku]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[9782324018121]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_regular_price]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[29.95]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_sale_price]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[15]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_low_stock_amount]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[3]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_weight]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1.406]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_length]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[22]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_width]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[28.9]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_height]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[31]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_price]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[15]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_product_image_gallery]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[116]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[ocean_sidebar]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[0]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[ocean_second_sidebar]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[0]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[ocean_disable_margins]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[enable]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[ocean_display_top_bar]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[default]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[ocean_display_header]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[default]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[ocean_center_header_left_menu]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[0]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[ocean_custom_header_template]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[0]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[ocean_header_custom_menu]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[0]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[ocean_menu_typo_font_family]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[0]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[ocean_disable_title]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[default]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[ocean_disable_heading]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[default]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[ocean_disable_breadcrumbs]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[default]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[ocean_display_footer_widgets]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[default]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[ocean_display_footer_bottom]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[default]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[ocean_custom_footer_template]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[0]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_yoast_wpseo_content_score]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[90]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key
        ><![CDATA[_yoast_wpseo_estimated-reading-time-minutes]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_yoast_wpseo_primary_product_cat]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[17]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_yoast_wpseo_focuskw]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[Livre]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_yoast_wpseo_linkdex]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[38]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_upsell_ids]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value
        ><![CDATA[a:3:{i:0;i:1266;i:1;i:2118;i:2;i:2958;}]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_wp_page_template]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[default]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_yoast_wpseo_wordproof_timestamp]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[shopengine_product_views_count]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[9]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_crosssell_ids]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[a:1:{i:0;i:1266;}]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

getXML.php

```
<?php
$file = "testxml.xml";
function getFeed($feed_url) {
    //Prend le contenu du fichier
    $feeds = file_get_contents($feed_url);
    //$search  = array('<content:encoded>', '</content:encoded>', '<wp:meta_value>', '</wp:meta_value>');
    //$replace = array('<contentEncoded>', '</contentEncoded>', '<wpMeta_value>', '</wpMeta_value>');
    $feeds = str_replace("<content:encoded>","<contentEncoded>",$feeds);
    $feeds = str_replace("</content:encoded>","</contentEncoded>",$feeds);
    $feeds = str_replace("<wp:postmeta>","<wpPostmeta>",$feeds);
    $feeds = str_replace("</wp:postmeta>","</wpPostmeta>",$feeds);
    //$feeds = str_replace("<wp:meta_key>","<wpMetaKey>",$feeds);
    //$feeds = str_replace("</wp:meta_key>","</wpMetaKey>",$feeds);
    
    //$feeds = str_replace("<wp:meta_value>","<wpMetavalue>",$feeds);
    //$feeds = str_replace("</wp:meta_value>","</wpMetavalue>",$feeds);
    
    $rss = simplexml_load_string($feeds);
    //var_dump($rss);
echo "<ul>";
$x=$rss;
    
    foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
        //Lien et titre WP
        echo "<li><a href='$entry->link' title='$entry->title'>" . $entry->title . "</a></li>";
        //Description 
        echo "<li>".htmlspecialchars($entry->contentEncoded)."</li>";
        //Contenu de chacune des catégorie pour ID, ISBN, etiquette
        foreach($entry->category as $elements)
        {
            echo "<li>$elements</li>";
        }
        foreach($entry->wpPostmeta as $metaDatas)
        {
            echo "<li>$metaDatas</li>";
        }
    }
echo "</ul>";
}
$test=getFeed($file);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found a syntax error in my test file:

```
$feeds = file_get_contents($feed_url);
    $feeds = str_replace(
        array("<content:encoded>","</content:encoded>","<wp:postmeta>","</wp:postmeta>",'<wp:meta_key>','</wp:meta_key>','<wp:meta_value>','</wp:meta_value>'),
        array("<contentEncoded>", "</contentEncoded>","<wpPostmeta>","</wpPostmeta>",'<wpMetaKey>','</wpMetaKey>','<wpMetaValue>','</wpMetaValue>'),
        $feeds
    );
    $rss = simplexml_load_string($feeds);
```

This now works fine with the large XML (about 77k lines) from WordPress WooCommerce.